# How to find the types for functions and variables that are imported from third party package or library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Can someone explain me how to find the exact types for a variable, function, Html tags, event param in event handler and event.target type

For example ExpressJS officially don't have the typescript support in it's documentation. So how to find the type of a variable or method

and also how to find the type of html tags or event object.

Please Share tips and documentation if any

I tried by hovering the cursor on function and hover to find the type but some are worked and some are not.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) project has a **huge** set of type definitions for projects that don't provide their own type definitions. For instance, the Express types are [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/express). If your project uses a package manager, you can install `@types/express` to get them (for instance, in an `npm`-managed project: `npm install --save-dev @types/express`).

Comment: How to find the types after installing the @types/express package. What is the way? @t-j-crowder

Comment: @workK - The types annotate the objects exported by Express, so you just import things from the `"express"` package. Was there something in particular you were having trouble importing?